# Does anyone know of a textbook for first order logic that...

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

1. Doesn't focus primarily on metalogic.
2. Covers every subtlety of first order logic that doesn't involve metalogic.
3. Has plenty of exercise to test if you truly understand the material.

Comment: Your requests (1) and (2) contradict each other.

Comment: And, IMO, you *should* care about compactness; one of my favorite applications is that it allows for an *extremely* simple way to lay the foundations for nonstandard analysis.

Comment: Your requirements on a logic textbook seem to be illogical. Perhaps you should study a good textbook on logic to help you write more logical questions.

Comment: @Rob I upvoted your comment. And I didn't know that asking for a textbook on logic without metalogic was illogical. I guess asking for a textbook on physics without metaphysics must be illogical too.

Comment: What exactly do you consider "metalogic"? (In particular, your dismissal of compactness in your original version of the question is deeply confusing - what do you want out of first-order logic?)

Comment: @TomislavOstojich I think Rob was probably observing that "Covers every subtlety of first order logic" directly contradicts your apparent interpretation of "metalogic" - if compactness is considered metalogic, then there's nothing in first-order logic which *isn't* metalogic.

Comment: "what do you want out of first-order logic?"

To prove things **using** first order logic. That is, I want a textbook that teaches me how to prove theorems in first-order theories without too much of a focus on first-order logic itself.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich That should be made clear in the question, then (that is, don't just say what you *don't* want). And I'm honestly *still* a bit confused. Are you just asking for a proof calculus, and a text on how to use it? You can find this in Enderton's book (or plenty of places online). Are you interested in "efficient proof search?" Then the literature on *automated theorem proving* (and the related proof-theoretic literature) is a good place to start. Are there *particular* first-order theories you're interested in? Some theories have special properties (e.g. decision procedures). Etc.

Comment: The problem is, just understanding "how to prove theorems in first-order theories" is a really small amount of material (which is why you can't find texts devoted to it). So without knowing more specifically what you're interested in, it will be difficult to recommend something you'll find useful.

Comment: Maybe useful: Yves Nievergelt, [Logic Mathematics and Computer Science: Modern Foundations with Practical Applications](https://books.google.it/books?id=AInDCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2015)

Comment: @Tomislav Ostojich: I guess I understand your request. You are looking for a textbook on practical logic. I described the scope of practical logic in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2415860/7011 so you can check whether my guess is correct. It is not the first time I encounter hostility towards practical formal logic. I suggest that we move discussion to a more welcoming place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat misguided, because the study of logic is, *by definition*, metalogic. That is, things like first-order theories are the *objects* being studied.

The practice of proving things in a first-order theory rightly belong to the subjects those theories represent — e.g. the art of proving things in a first-order theory of real analysis is something you learn from a real analysis textbook, not from a logic textbook. The *practical* contribution that logic gives would be to teach you about things like how to set up the subject as a first-order theory or as a tool for defining kinds of objects (like abstract vector spaces).

What I *think* you're looking for exists, but it's not as a *logic* textbook. What you're looking for is basically something like an "introduction to higher mathematics" type of book that's geared towards preparing the reader for a more rigorous study of mathematics, including things like how to make rigorous formal arguments

Comment: Introduction to higher mathematics books (henceforth IHMB) are, unfortunately, not very good at teaching precise reasoning. Why is it that the type of proof techniques found in IHMB have no resemblance whatsoever to the kind of proof techniques found in automated theorem provers? Why is it sooo non-trivial to translate a proof in an IHMB into a computer-checkable format? These questions are profound mysteries to all postdocs.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich "These questions are profound mysteries to all postdocs." Um, no, it's not really a mystery at all. The reason it's hard to do this translation is that human-written proofs tend to sweep *lots* of stuff under the rug. Now you might view this as a bad thing (I think it's mixed), but it does explain why it's hard to mechanize human-written proofs in general. (Incidentally, there's a lot of interesting work on figuring out what *kinds* of under-the-rug-sweeping are harder to mechanize than others ...)

Comment: “What I think you're looking for exists, but it's not as a logic textbook.” I do not agree. A textbook that covers practical aspects of formal logic (proof system, graphical presentation) belong to logic. What else can it be? It should not be called “higher mathematics” because its goal is not to expound some mathematics, its goal is to expound rules of logical thinking.